# Determining circle radius/angle from an arc chord.

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

I have to admit upfront that while I did fine at high school Geometry, it probably remains one of the subjects where I thought, 'okay, when am I ever going to use this ?' And sort of blanked it out of my mind for direct reference.

Notably, this is not the *only* subject that has 'come back to bite me', or in undergrad studying first in Philosophy, I took a course on logic, where we learned about 'truth tables'-- And lo-and-behold, some 15 years later I find in FPGA's and system state logic, what do you have, but 'truth tables !'.

In any case, unfortunately my 'geometry' is maybe a little *too* far back and too fuzzy. But I am trying to work on a little side project at the time, and rather than 'theoretical' this actually applies to a 'real world' type example:

[image: Chords]

So say I have this series of arcs/chords, and I am trying to determine the radius of the circle they are composed of.

I know there are formula's out there such as [this](https://www.cuemath.com/questions/how-to-find-the-radius-of-a-circle-with-a-chord/).

But that requires you to know 'h' or how far the center of the circle is.

Since these drawings/sketches come off a piece of machinery, let's just say it is 'not reasonably possible' for me to figure out the actual origin of the circle.

Yet, it seems there must be some other way I can determine the figures that I want, no ?

But... I'm a little confused as to how to go about it, or what formulae to use.

Sorry for being 'naïve' or just 'forgetting', but any assistance is greatly appreciated.

### Best,

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. We don't need exposition like the one you provided in the first few paragraphs nor do we need a "signature." I think there is a way to solve this problem by constructing some clever triangles but I can't see the solution.

Comment: A chord could belong to any circle with diameter not more than the chord length. And with a circular arc (make sure that the arcs are strictly circular, not just random hand drawings) one can construct the center of the circle to which they belong: draw any two chords on the arc. Construct the perpendicular bisectors of the two chords. The intersection point of the bisectors is the center. Now measure the distance from center to arc. I don’t know how one could derive any formula when we do not know anything about the arc itself.

Comment: Is the chord circular or not? If not, then the problem becomes significantly more complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you choose should depend on what information about the arc is easiest to measure. Two variables that seem convenient are the length of the intersecting chord (w) and the what i'll call the height of the arc (w)

this is your arc
[image]
This is the given arc shown in the circle we are looking for.
[image]
$$\begin{align}
 \frac{w}{2}\cdot \frac{w}{2} = h \cdot (2r-h) && \text{by intersecting chords theorem}\\
 \frac{w^2}{4} = 2rh -h^2  \\
\frac{w^2}{8h} + \frac{h}{2} = r\\
\end{align} $$
And there you have it.

Link to intersecting chords theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem

Comment: Thanks PMXI, that's great ! I'll try it out. And to regard the other commenters... I just felt telling a little 'background story' would at least be fun (i.e. as in-- I'm not looking to 'cheat' or just have someone help me with my homework.... :/)

Comment: @AnthonyBalducci The community appreciates your efforts to include context, but if you will notice, the second paragraph of the question contains nothing relevant to the question.